# How do I integrate over this measure?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives

I'm have trouble understanding the following few statement:

*Let $\Psi$ be a measure on $[0,\pi/2]$ such that $\Psi([0,\theta]) = \frac{3}{2}\sin^2\theta$*. Then $\Psi$ satisfies
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}\cos\theta\,\Psi(d\theta) = \int_0^{\pi/2}\sin\theta\,\Psi(d\theta) = 1
$$
**Question:** Why is this statement correct? I guess I don't understand how to integrate over the function $\frac{3}{2}\sin^2\theta$. I figured out that if we do
$$
\dfrac{d}{d\theta}\bigg(\frac{3}{2}\sin^2\theta\bigg) = 3\sin\theta\cos\theta
$$
so that
$$
d\dfrac{3}{2}\sin^2\theta = 3\sin\theta\cos\theta \,d\theta
$$
and plug this into the integral, we get
$$
\int_0^{\pi/2}3\sin\theta\cos^2\theta\,d\theta = 1
$$
**What I don't understand** is why $\Psi(d\theta) = 3\sin\theta\cos\,d\theta$.

Comment: You're interested in the relative change with respect to $d \theta$ of the measure. The relative rate of change of $\frac{3}{2} \sin^2 (\theta)$ with respect to $d \theta$ is exactly given by its derivative. As you calculated, the derivative has $3 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)$ as value. So $d (\frac{3}{2} \sin^2 (\theta)) = d \theta 3 \sin(\theta) \cos(\theta)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$d\psi(\theta)$ is same as $\psi'(\theta)d\theta$. The derivative of $\frac 3 2 \sin^{2}\theta$ is $3\sin \theta \cos \theta$. And $\int_0^{\pi /2} \sin \theta (3\sin \theta) \cos \theta d\theta=(\sin \theta)^{3}|_0^{\pi/2}=1$. Similarly, $\int_0^{\pi /2} \cos \theta (3\sin \theta) \cos \theta d\theta=-(\cos \theta)^{3}|_0^{\pi/2}=1$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but what I don't understand is why $\Psi(d\theta) = 3\sin\theta\cos\theta\,d\theta$. Could you elaborate on this?

Comment: By chain rule derivative of $sin^{2}(x)$ is $2sin \, x cos \,x$

Comment: Okay thanks! One more thing, you write $d\Psi(\theta)$ is the same as $\Psi'(\theta)d\theta$. But in the example, it's $\Psi(d\theta)$ not $\Psi(\theta)$. Could you clarify?

Comment: $d\Psi(\theta)$ is same as $\Psi(d\theta)$.